# Windows7 cannot find Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, system-installation

I recently partitioned my hard drive which was running on Ubuntu 14.04LTS, using a USB flash. Then I installed Windows7 on the new partition. Now I cannot find the Ubuntu OS. I expected at startup to be given the option of running either Ubuntu or Windows7 but I found that Windows just runs by default. Any suggestions on what I can do to resurrect the Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to recover your GRUB, Windows overrides the bootloader when you install it after Ubuntu. You can find a Tutorial here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

Comment: Thanks Will give a try and get back. It turns out I may need to download boot-repair, may take a while. 
Nato

Comment: It worked! I followed instructions on the link - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows. Thanks. Nato

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

[EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

That will allow you to modify your boot loader to accommodate Ubuntu.

I prefer grub2 ;)

Also, I've never used this, so that's as far as I can take you, but a lot of people use this and will probably suggest the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think repairing the system by a live media is much better than to reinstall the whole system, and windows works on NTFS it cannot Detect ext4 or any other format, so you will never see Ubuntu partition on your computer but if you see memory blocks by memory management option you will see partitions